# Using C# and regex to parse source code and find function calls with arguments

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have a list of function calls stored in a database, and for some function calls, I care about what the arguments of the function call are.  I am parsing C source code with my program (which is in C#).  I'm trying to find the best way of getting the function calls with the arguments.  I read the source code into a string prior to parsing it (so that I am not using the stream reader on the file).  I tried using some regex (which is somewhat new to me) to parse the source file, but was retrieving more than just the function call when using a regex string like this:   functionCall + ".*\\)"; ( I am escaping the opening ( in the function call)

The function calls are stored in the following format in the DB

```
Function Call
============
some_Call(
```

There is a reason they are stored this way, and will  not change.

Is there a good way to do this through regex, or would I be better suited to walk through the source code contents?

Let me know if any clarification is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part of the reason your solution failed is that you probably should have used `.*?)`, instead of greedy matching.

A complete answer would have to follow at least these:

Ignore parenthesis in strings and chars (which you can do with a regex, although with escaping it can be a little complicated)

```
functionCall("\")", ')')
```

Ignore parentheses in comments (which you can do with a regex)

```
functionCall(/*)*/ 1, // )
2)
```

Don't match too much (which you can do with a regex)

```
functionCall(1) + functionCall(2) + (2 * 3) // Don't match past the first )
```

but it would also have to ignore balanced parentheses

```
functionCall((1+(1))*(2+2))
```

This last one is something you can't do with a normal regex, because it involves counting parenthesis, and is generally something that regexs aren't suited for.  However, it appears that [.NET has ways to do this](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx).

(And technically you would have to handle macros, I can imagine a

```
#define close_paren )
```

would ruin your day...)

That said, you could likely come up with a naive solution (similar to what you had, or what some other poster recommends) and it would work for many cases, especially if you're working with known inputs.

Comment: While not suited to it, .Net Regex supports matching groups and this should be supported.

Comment: I cleansed the source code string by removing comments, carriage returns, and what I classified as preprocessor directives (anything starting with #).  Also, I am almost certain (at least at this time) that nobody is using nested parens in the function calls we are using.

Comment: Also, the amount of calls that i need to retrieve the arguments for is a very small subset of the function calls, so I shouldn't run into any funky syntax hopefully, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a quick regex and tested it, check the following:

```
            string tst = "some_function(type<whatever> tesxt_112,type<whatever> tesxt_113){";

        Regex r = new Regex(".*\\((.*)\\)");
        Match m = r.Match(tst);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            string[] arguments = m.Groups[1].Value.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Argument " + (i + 1) + " = " + arguments[i]);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

So the output for the above string would be:

Argument 1 = type<whatever> tesxt_112

Argument 2 = type<whatever> tesxt_113

Hope this helps:

Andrew :-)

Comment: What I really need is your "tst" string from the source code itself, but this will be super useful once i get that :-)

Comment: Are you having trouble getting this value from the DB?

Comment: I used Daniel L's solution to find the function line and your solution to get the arguments

Answer (score 0):

Not to deteriorate you but... in C, I believe (vaguely) that you can do this:

```
void secondFunction() { /* no-op */ }

void firstFunction()
{
    void* xyz = secondFunction;

    xyz(); // this should call secondFunction
}
```

Is that a possible scenario? And what about other variants of pointer usages?!?

Say, type casting functional-style?!?

```
int a;
float b = float(a); // call to the "float" function?!? NO! it's a type casting
```

Use a list of predefined types? What if the conversion was to a custom structs and what about typedefs? Now you'd have to parse those too!

Seriously, use a parser!! There're [several available options](http://www.google.co.th/search?&q=C+parser) already that could parse C.

I think Regex is a rather bad tool for the job.